# Have you ever seen the request's body in the post to be exchanged between 2 requests, when you use HttpClient in an Async way?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, exchange-server, dotnet-httpclient

The customer reported that 2 registers exchanged information with each other, and on a thousand requests only 2.
Register A has body information about register B and vice versa.
That occurred in my environment first time during a throble in the network.
Here you can see how I create my HTTP client and use it.
If you have any additional help, please let me know, many thanks for all!

How do I call the Exec from a controller and service?

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseModel>> Exec(RequestModel model) 
{ 
   return await _service.Exec(model); 
}
```

#### Service Layer

```
public async Task<ResponseModel> Exec (Request model)
{ 
   return await _service.Exec(model); 
}
```

#### Dal Layer

```
public async Task<ResponseModel> Exec(RequestModel model)
{
   var httpClientHandler = HttpClientHandler();
   httpClientHandler.UseProxy = true;
   var proxy = new WebProxy
   {
      Address = new Uti("proxy_uri",
      BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
      UseDefaultCredentials = true
   };

   httpClientHandler .Proxy = proxy;

   var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "endpoint_uri");
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization","your token auth");
   
   string jsonStr = Json.Serializer.Serialize(model);
   var content = new StringContent(jsonStr, null, "application/json");
   request.Content = content;
   
   var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

   return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ResponseModel>();
}
```

I couldn't simulate this situation, but I believe that I had made a mistake or misused the HTTP Client implementation.
I use webapi project target framework netcoreapp3.1.
System.Net.Http version=4.2.2.0

Comment: As a side-note, the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application. This shouldn't have anything to do with your problem though.

Comment: `Have you ever` never. I'd suspect the code that calls the identical `Exec` methods mixes them up. I don't know what you mean by throble, but if you meant throttling problem, it's likely the code (which is missing) failed to handle this and returned a previous result. The class names suggest an unsuitable architecture too. Exchange is a remote service, not a data storage.

Comment: I *strongly* suggest you look at [Typed Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#typed-clients), registered with `AddHttpClient` in conjunction with [Polly retry strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory.). You already have to make major changes - .NET Core 3.1 reached End-of-Life last year. The oldest supported .NET Core version right now is .NET 6, and .NET 8 is in RC1

Comment: AddHttpClient will properly register, reuse and recycle HttpClient instances even in .NET Core 3.1. NET 6's [PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-7.0) will eliminate  the entire `Dal.Exec` method. Polly will retry or throttle requests as needed.